# What are the parameter requirements for 'Client ID' in IBM Watson Dialog Service conversation endpoint? [Bluemix]

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-dialog

To start a conversation on WDS, the `/conversation` endpoint is invoked with `client_id` (an integer) as described in the [IBM documentation](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/apis/dialog-apis.html#!/Conversation/obtainResponse)

However, there seems to be a further restriction / requirement on `client_id`. If I pass `client_id` as 100000, it's successful; but if I pass 400000, it fails with `{"code":400, "error": "The client_id specified is invalid. It does not exist."}`

```
$ curl -i --data "client_id=190000" -X POST "http://.../v1/dialogs/40df25ae-xxx-yyy-zzz-ca7/conversation"

HTTP/1.1 201 Created
X-Backside-Transport: OK OK,OK OK
```

vs

```
$ curl -i --data "client_id=400000" -X POST "http://.../v1/dialogs/40df25ae-xxx-yyy-zzz-ca7/conversation"

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
X-Backside-Transport: FAIL FAIL,FAIL FAIL
...
...
{"code":400, "error": "The client_id specified is invalid. It does not exist."}
```

This seems to be a recent issue. I've been using the service and only recently have I started seeing these errors.

Any recent change? And if so, is it documented?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send the `client_id` to start a conversation.
It's an **optional** parameter and If you don't specified it, a new `client_id` will be issued.

You can test this by running:

```
curl -i -X POST "http://.../v1/dialogs/40df25ae-xxx-yyy-zzz-ca7/conversation"
```

more than once.

Comment: Yes, I know it's an optional parameter. For my case, I opt to pass it. My question is whether there are any requirements / restrictions (apart from the fact that it should be an integer).

Comment: leave it blank because you only pass it when you have previously created it. So the number you send needs to be created by the service not you. You can create the number as I'm suggesting in my answer

Comment: Just tested. It only works if you do pass client_id parameter with value as blank; but doesn't work if you do not pass client_id at all (per your example).
So it really is a mandatory parameter. Misleading documentation? Or am I missing something?

Comment: if you don't send a `client_id` it works. I just tested.

Comment: Please share your working request. Mine is as indicated on the question

Answer (score 0):

German is correct. In your initial call you should not be passing through a client_id. All you would pass is the dialog_id. You will get back in the response a new client_id, a new conversation_id, and the text response which would be your first output element. 
Going forward, you would pass the client_id to continue using the user profile that was previously connected with the client_id, so everytime this user chats you should pass the same client_id if you want to remember them.

You will pass the same conversation_id for the entire session, but generate a new one (by not passing one) for subsequent conversations with the same user.